# Joomla date from being published

Tags: joomla

How to write a module that displays on article days from being published?

I wrote something like that but it doesnt seem to work everytime.

Could you guys correct me?

```
{source}

<?php
    $option = JRequest::getCmd('option');
    $view = JRequest::getCmd('view');
    if ($option=="com_content" && $view=="article") {
    $ids = explode(':',JRequest::getString('id'));
    $article_id = $ids[0];
    $article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
    $article->load($article_id);
    $date = new JDate($article->get("publish_up"));

    $currentTime = new JDate('now');

    $interval = $date->diff($currentTime);

    if($interval->d == 0) {
            echo 'dzisiaj' . "<br>";
        }
        else if( $interval->d == 1) {
            echo 'wczoraj' . "<br>";
        }
        else if( $interval->d > 1) {
            echo $interval->format('%a dni temu') . "<br>";
        }


}

?>

{/source}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you get the article id looks strange. Try instead something like this:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication(); 
$article_id = $app->input->getInt('id');
```

This uses the current joomla api for fetching http variables ( [more info here](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) )

Still, I dont see exactly why your code should fail the way you are doing it...

Comment: I did it, and now it works but it gets wrong id of the article. It should get 41 but gets 22.

$article_id = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('id');

I think this line is not working as it should work;

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but now i have something like this

```
{source}
<?php


    $app = JFactory::getApplication(); 
    $article_id = $app->input->getInt('id');
    $article =& JTable::getInstance("content");
    $article->load($article_id);
    $date = new JDate($article->get("published"));
    $currentTime = new JDate('now');
    echo $date;
    $interval = $date->diff($currentTime);

    if($interval->d == 0) {
            echo 'dzisiaj';
        }
        else if( $interval->d == 1) {
            echo 'wczoraj';
        }
        else if( $interval->d > 1) {
            echo $interval->format('%a dni temu');
        }




?>

{/source}
```

and it works now, but it shows incorect date of publishment.